# Example Obtain the IOLink packet

Tags: protocols

Recently, I was analyzing the IOLink agreement. I only found the document of the agreement, but I didn't understand it very well. I want to read the newspaper to understand the format of the agreement.

I found the protocol documentation, but to no avail